# Error from com.google.android.gms

Tags: android

I found the exception from device emulator. It is coming from `com.google.android.gms`.

```
1116-31507/com.google.android.gms E/CursorLeakDetecter﹕ PossibleCursorLeak:content://com.google.android.gms.common.stats.net.contentprovider/networkrawreport,QueryCounter:5
    android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:399)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:316)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.net.NetworkReportService.a(SourceFile:141)
            at com.google.android.gms.gcm.am.run(SourceFile:129)
```

Comment: post your code to resolve your problem...

Comment: it is not from gcm it is from your db cursor which you forgot to close

Comment: I could not get any code line trace

Comment: @MohammodHossain accept any answer if your issue is resolved for SO users.

Answer (score 1):

either you're calling getReadableDatabase() method twice
OR make sure to close cursor before closing database.